# Ckeditor getdata() function is not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I used `withinput()` function to return back with form values but it's not working for ckeditor, that's why I tried getting value with Ckeditor `getdata()` function but it's also didn't work.

Ckeditor Form is like:

```
<?php echo Form::text("PageLanguage[description][$language>id]",
old("PageLanguage[description][$language->id]"), 
array('id' =>"description-$language->id",'class' => 'form-control'));
?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I used textarea and it worked in my code
If you use `Form::text` it can't get value that's why it will save null value, you must change `Form::text` to `Form::textarea` like that:

```
<?php echo Form::textarea("PageLanguage[description][$language->id]",
old("PageLanguage[description][$language->id]"), 
array('id' =>"description-$language->id",'class' => 'form-control'));?>
```